# Difference between direct sum of vector spaces and direct sum of representations.

Tags: vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory, direct-sum

> Let $G$ be a group. Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces which have the structures of $G$-modules. If $U \simeq V \oplus W$ as vector spaces then can't we say that they are same as $G$-modules? My teacher says that if $U$ is a direct sum of vector spaces then the matrix associated with the corresponding representation is a $2 \times 2$ upper triangular block matrix which is not necessarily diagonal. The matrix is diagonal if and only if $U \simeq V \oplus W$ as $G$-modules.

Could anyone please shed some light on what is being meant?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you gone through the link @rshwieb?

Comment: If $V \cap W \neq (0)$ then how can we assure that the contribution from $V \to W$ is zero even if we take a basis of $V$ and extend it to a basis of $V + W\ $? I am not quite sure about it @rschwieb.

Comment: You *can't* guarantee the contribution $V\to W$ is zero if $V\cap W\neq\{0\}$. That was my point... the sum is direct when that part is zero.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've written you must mean $U$ is also some given $kG$ module.

There is no assurance that the isomorphism $U\cong V\oplus W$ is $G$-linear.  It may indeed have the same dimension as $V\oplus W$ (for that is all a vector space isomorphism buys you) and yet its $kG$ structure may differ from that of $V\oplus W$ considered as a $kG$ module.

For example, choose $k=\mathbb C$ and $G$ the cyclic group of order $2$.  It's got two nonisomorphic one-dimensional representations $M_1$ and $M_2$, so $M_1\oplus M_2\cong M_1\oplus M_1$ as vector spaces, but not as representations.

---

Given your discussion of nondiagonal representations, I think maybe your context has not been described completely. Let's suppose $M_1$ and $M_2$ are subrepresentations of a given representation, and that we want to know about $M_1+M_2$ as a representation.  To say that $M_1+M_2=M_1\oplus M_2$ means that the representation can be diagonalized. Otherwise you can only put it in upper triangular form, and the upper right hand block shows to what degree $M_1$ and $M_2$ are mixed with each other.  When $M_1\cap M_2=\{0\}$ that block can be made zero everywhere.

Comment: What makes the $k [G]$-module structure different? Do you mean $G$-module structure on $U$ is not obtained by summing up the $G$-actions on $V$ and $W\ $?

Comment: Why is the representation on $U$ given by $\rho_U (g) = \begin{pmatrix} \rho_V (g) & \pi (g) \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for some $\pi : G \longrightarrow V^{\ast}\ $?

Comment: See here https://youtu.be/BZI5C8H_Jy0

Comment: @AnilBagchi. From your initial description, I can only assume $U$ is some given representation. The action could be anything. Otherwise, what is it?  The action of $V\oplus W$ is certainly obtained by summing up the actions, yes, but why would it have anything to do with the structure of $U$?

Comment: I don't understand how can the representation $U$ be written in the upper triangular matrix form of specific kind @rschwieb. Also how it is related to the representation $V.$ Please have a look at the link. It will not take more than 2 minutes.

Comment: Why is $(2,1)$-th block taken to be zero? Why isn't it zero in $(1,2)$-th block?

Comment: @AnilBagchi. If you have $V$ and $W$ then you also have $V+W$ (no $\oplus$).  By picking a basis of $V$ and then extending it to a basis of $V+W$ you are guaranteed to have an upper triangular representation. But eliminating on the upper right block is not possible unless the sum is direct.

Comment: You can also make it lower triangular, it doesn't matter. The thing is that you can't get it diagonal without the direct sum.

Comment: I am actually confused. Could you give me an example? If you take $V + W$ then an element of it could have several expressions as a sum of elements of $V$ and $W.$ Then what is it's block matrix expression?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141436/discussion-between-anil-bagchi-and-rschwieb).